# Does Tomcat call the doPost method of a servlet before or after it receives the post body?

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets

When Tomcat receives a Post request that is routed to a servlet, does Tomcat wait until it gets the entire post body before calling the servlet's handler method, or does it call the method immediately?

I have created a simple servlet by extending the `HttpServlet` class and implementing a `doPost(request, response)` method. Within my method, I'm calling `request.getInputStream()` to retrieve the post body via an input stream.

Suppose the client is posting a very large object, and partway through the upload, the client aborts the upload or their internet connection fails. Will my `doPost` method never get called in this case? Or will it get called, but fail while in the process of reading the input stream?

The difference is important to me because I want to figure out if I would be able to catch an `IOException` during the input stream read and take some action there.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at Tomcat source code we see that the default `ServeltInputStream` implementation is the `CoyoteInputStream` which reads from an instance of `org.apache.catalina.connector.InputBuffer`. This buffer have various extending classes which are protocol specific. It appears that the request body being fully read before `doPost()` is called is an implementation detail depending on the protocol used e.g. for HTTP2 in `StreamInputBuffer` class we see the following comment:

> Two buffers are required to avoid various multi-threading issues.
>       These issues arise from the fact that the Stream (or the
>       Request/Response) used by the application is processed in one thread
>       but the connection is processed in another. Therefore it is possible
>       that a request body frame could be received before the application
>       is ready to read it. If it isn't buffered, processing of the
>       connection (and hence all streams) would block until the application
>       read the data. Hence the incoming data has to be buffered.
>       If only one buffer was used then it could become corrupted if the
>       connection thread is trying to add to it at the same time as the
>       application is read it. While it should be possible to avoid this
>       corruption by careful use of the buffer it would still require the
>       same copies as using two buffers and the behaviour would be less
>       clear.

This applies to other servlet containers e.g. JBoss WildFly can start executing `doPost()` before request body is fully read based on [[WFLY-6671] ajp connection hangs if a post HTTP request header contains 'Transfer-Encoding: chunked'](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/WFLY-6671) if the connection can hang inside.

Comment: Thanks for the great response. I tested this by aborting some large uploads and found that, indeed, my function is being called during the upload, and I get an IOException as I try to read the stream. Which is what I was hoping for.

Answer (score 0):

The `doPost()` method will be called before reading the body.

In usual POST requests the body is read and consumed when you call `request.getParameter(..)`, `.getParameterNames()`, `.getPart(..)` or `.getParts()`. If you are able to call `request.getInputStream()` it means that the body has not been read yet.

With HTTP/1.1 protocol the server may send an acknowledge to the client (`100 Continue`) if the client has asked for it with an `Expect` header. It happens just before reading the body.

Comment: This isn't strictly speaking true - `doPost` is certainly called before the entire request is read, but there is no guarantee that no part of the body has been read.